# Unable to set up PostgreSQL in Travis CI because before_script doesn't work

Tags: node.js, postgresql, travis-ci

I try to set up a postgresql database to test one NodeJS project ([GitHub](https://github.com/haoliangyu/pg-reactive)) but fail on initializing it. What I want to do is to create a custom credential and database using `before_script`, however Travis CI seems unable to run all before_scripts. Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js

services:
  - postgresql

addons:
  postgresql: "9.5"


node_js:
  - "node"

install:
  - yarn

before_script:
  - psql -c "CREATE DATABASE rx_reactive_test;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "CREATE USER rx_reactive_tester WITH PASSWORD '1esdf3143';" -U postgres

script:
- npm test

cache: yarn
```

No psql command is run during the build process and I have got following error when running my tests:

```
 Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)

  at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)

  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)
```

For a detailed report, please check https://travis-ci.org/haoliangyu/pg-reactive/jobs/214507951. I have spent hours on searching for solutions to it but I don't much luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you are installing `yarn` that's a Node.js module, and then at the same time you say

```
node_js:
  - "node"
```

This doesn't look right.

Here's an example from my [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library that's always worked:

```
language: node_js
sudo: required
dist: trusty
node_js:
  - "4"
  - "6"
  - "7"
addons:
  postgresql: "9.5"
script: "npm run travis"
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database pg_promise_test;' -U postgres
  - node test/db/init.js
```

NOTE: It is important to get the lines formatted correctly also ;)

Comment: I copy exactly the same travis CI configuration from pg-promise but it still doesn't create the new database for me. I end up using the default travis database for testing.

Comment: BTW, the "node" means using the latest stable Node.js release. See: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Specifying-Node.js-versions